# Change tileset for already-created Starcraft 2 map?

Tags: starcraft-2, galaxy-editor

I started making a custom map and I want to change the tileset to a different one, is there a menu setting for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you open Map > Map Options... then go to the Texture tab, then you can change the tileset. Note that changing the tileset will wipe the undo history.